# Geometry Nodes: What is the difference between "Index" and "ID" node?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

Recently started learning *Geometry Nodes* properly (though I have already been using it occasionally). I noticed that there isn't much difference between the "Index" node and "ID" node apparently. Am I missing something? Please explain.

[image: Using ID]

[image: Using Index]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/id.html

Answer (score 2):

*I will try a simple explanation:*

You can think of the ID of an element as an individual numerical value.

Unlike the index, which is always a consecutive number for each attribute domain and is unchangeable, the ID can be set and used individually.

Usually, the ID for an element within a node tree is set manually with the node [Set ID](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/write/set_id.html), or is generated by the node [Distribute Points on Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html), for example, and is not available by default.

If you query the ID in an attribute domain and it has not been created before, the index of the element is always used instead.

This is also the reason why it makes no difference in your case (and as it does in most applications).

However, [Index](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/input_index.html) should always be used, unless you know exactly that you need the [ID](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/id.html) instead and that the required values can be found there, because if you create a node tree that is actually dependent on the index of an element and use this node tree as a group in combination with another setup where the ID was created before, unforeseen results may occur.